# Prometheus metrics not give path variable values

Tags: maven, java-8, prometheus, micrometer, spring-boot-2

Code sample from spring boot application, which is producing prometheus metrics.

I am trying to access it with http://localhost:8080/myApi/ABC.

But In prometheus metrics it is producing the metrics with **"uri=/myApi/{refNum}"**.

**Promotheus metrics:**

```
my_example_api_seconds{application="my-application",exception="None", method="GET", outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/myApi/{refNum}",quantile="0.3",} 14.495514624
```

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;    
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import io.micrometer.spring.autoconfigure.MeterRegistryCustomizer;

@Configuration
public class BeansConfiguration {
@Bean
    MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> meterRegistryMeterRegistryCustomizer(MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        return meterRegistry1 -> {
            meterRegistry.config().commonTags("application","my-application");
        };
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;

   @Timed(
            value="my.example.api",
            percentiles = {0.30,0.50,0.95,0.99}
    )
    @GetMapping(value = "myApi/{refNum}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> fun(@NotNull @PathVariable("refNum") String refNum) {
     ...
    }
```

Pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <micrometer.version>1.2.0</micrometer.version>
  <prometheus.registry.version>1.2.0</prometheus.registry.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-spring-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus.registry.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
            <version>${prometheus.registry.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>io.prometheus</groupId>
            <artifactId>simpleclient_pushgateway</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as designed.

Imagine you had a user endpoint of `@GetMapping(value = "user/{userId}")`

If you were to call `user/1`, `user/2`, all the way to `user/1000000`, you would want the metrics system to record 1 metric with the aggregate timing off all the calls for that single endpoint.

To record individual calls, you would want to add a log message, not a metrics framework.